# How to use an address with Google Maps Geocoding and not with lon and lat

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

At the moment i am trying to find out how to use Google Maps Geocoding. I allready have a database that can store a address and a longitude and latitude and i also have it working to output it with a longitude and latitude.. but.. i want it to use a address rather than using a lon and lat. So let me explain what i want to do below:

On http://www.bartnooijens.nl/school/webapp-eindopdracht/#acti-toe users can add a new entry and can also add an Address. I want my Google Maps to read the address and place it onto the map. For now i have staticly stored the lon and lat into the database to get a marker on but that's not what i want.

MYSQL:

- Address (needs to be used for the google maps)
- lon (currently using for static lon, but not want to use a lon)
- lat (currently using for static lat, but not want to use a lat)

Below is my code that i have now and is working when i use a longitude and latitude.

I also tried to read from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro but my coding experiences are not good enough to get it working. So i hope you guys can help me out a little. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAsh1JAlWZL0SBacR3N94aVzrp4PPGQQeg&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

             function initialize(lat,lon,label,tekst) {

              // Instellen coordinaten uit de paramaters van de aanroep
              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

              // Opties voor de kaart, de coordinaten worden het middelpunt
               var myOptions = {
                 zoom: 15,
                 center: myLatlng,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
               }

              // Maak een nieuwe kaart aan met de ingestelde opties
               var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

              // Maak een infowindow met de tekst die via de parameter binnen kwam
               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   content: tekst
               });

              // Url van het icon dat op de kaart wordt gezet
               var image = 'images/maps-marker.png';

              // Plaats een marker op de opgegeven coordinaten
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: myLatlng,
                   map: map,
                   title: label,
                   icon: image
               });
              // Voeg een eventhandler toe voor het tonen van de info als iemand op de marker klikt
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                 infowindow.open(map,marker);
               });
             }

              function loadMap() {
              initialize('51.584294','4.795296','','');
              }
        </script>


</head>

<body  onload="loadMap()";>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick:

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var address = 'London, UK';

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 6
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
   });

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, but removing the first two arguments (lat,lon) and replacing them with the address, then using a modified `codeAddress` from [the google "simple geocoder" example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple):

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize(address, label, tekst) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var myLatlng = results[0].geometry.location;
      // Opties voor de kaart, de coordinaten worden het middelpunt
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      // Maak een nieuwe kaart aan met de ingestelde opties
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      // Maak een infowindow met de tekst die via de parameter binnen kwam
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: tekst
      });

      // Url van het icon dat op de kaart wordt gezet
      var image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png';

      // Plaats een marker op de opgegeven coordinaten
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        icon: image
      });
      // Voeg een eventhandler toe voor het tonen van de info als iemand op de marker klikt
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });

    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

function loadMap() {
  initialize('Hogeschoollaan, 4818 Breda, Netherlands', '', 'Hello World');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```